# To Xml on a string with a lambda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, activesupport

Why is the second example on Hash::To_xml being passed a lambda?

[Api Dock Hash to_xml](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Hash/to_xml)

```
'foo'.to_xml(lambda { |options, key| options[:builder].b(key) })
```

When I run it:

```
"es".to_xml(lambda { |options, key| options[:builder].b(key) }) 
*** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `to_xml' for "es":String
```

Comment: Your first question is answered right in the docs you supplied **"if value is a callable object it must expect one or two arguments. Depending on the arity, the callable is invoked with the options hash as first argument with key as :root, and key singularized as second argument. The callable can add nodes by using options[:builder]."** *"When I run it"*? Where are you running it from?

Comment: From a break point in a controller

Comment: After reading the documentation a little close what it means is actually calling like `{"es"=>lambda { |options,key| options[:builder].b(key) }}.to_xml` where `es` is the key and the lambda is the `value` object. this will generate `=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<hash>\n  <b>e</b>\n</hash>\n"` which strangely drops the "s" in "es" (possibly because it thinks "es" is plural??)

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you!